# php error undefined index with 2 variable

Tags: php

anyone can help me?
i used this code for managing pages
and it's get

> undefined index : page
>   undefined index : aksi

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'];
$aksi = $_GET['aksi'];
if($page == "") {
    if($aksi == "") {
        include "page/dashboard.php";
    }
} elseif($page == "dashboard") {
    if($aksi == "") {
         include "page/dashboard.php";
    }
}elseif($page == "masuk") {
    if($aksi == "") {
         include "page/kas_masuk/masuk.php";
    }
    if($aksi == "hapus") {
         include "page/kas_masuk/hapus.php";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: As Jigar Shah said, check the link in his comment.

Comment: thanks its done with $aksi = isset($_GET['aksi']) ? $_GET['aksi'] : '';

Answer (score -1):

Use `isset()` function like below,

**UPDATE**

To get value of `$_GET[]` use below

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:'');
$aksi = (isset($_GET['aksi'])?$_GET['aksi']:'');
```

Now we will get value if `$_GET[]` have value otherwise empty without returning any error or warning

Comment: That gives you something completely different - a boolean, depending on whether or not those GET parameter exist, but not their _values_ if they do.

Comment: the error dissapear, but now it wont change page, just change the address bar with the same page

Comment: @CBroe First i added the code for removing that given `undefined index` error. Now i changed the code to get value if it is there